# Pseudo code to copy pdfs from one directory to different directories on a server

Tags: c#

I have to write a program to copy pdfs from a directory and paste them in a  different directory.

I have an excel file which has the mapping of which pdf file has to to be copied from the main folder to a different sub folder.

I would just like a pseudo code to help me begin with the program.

My Idea is to select all files which has to be copied to the same folder first and repeat process till no files are left to be copied.

Help me improvise on this.

I have to make program which does this process in one click.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you go with a CSV file.

```
for i <= FileLength do
{
     Data[i] = Read.Trim(",")
     MoveFile(Data[1],Data[2])
}
```